# Displaying message once user has logged in facebook

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I'm letting the user log in to facebook using

```
loginBtn.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

which loads a new login window, what I'm trying to do is that when the window has closed, display a message saying login successful/unsuccessful. I've tried setting a timer that checks if there is an active connection that starts when the window opens and displays a toast when an active connection is established however this seems inefficient and doesn't work. Is there an oncomplete listener for a force login?

Answer (score 1):

From the Facebook Documentation:

Create a function to perform some logic when the session state changes:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception     exception) {
    //Do something
}
```

Create an implementation for the Session.StatusCallBack listener and call your function

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
     @Override
     public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
     }
};
```

Register the listener in your onCreate method using the UILifecycleHelper object

```
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper =  new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
```

There are other things you need to do to manage the session properly and it is explained in more detail [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/). This should get things going though.